# How to write a query in Firebase like SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = '1'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to write a query like getting the data from Firebase using PHP. Like I have to get all the data which status is 1.

Here is the Code:
[image: Here is the Code]

Comment: firebase is Non Relational Database, its not structured like MySql. If i could get the collection and document layout i can help with the query.

Comment: Hey Paul! Can you please provide how can I get the data from firebase like the upper query?

Comment: You can check the code "https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkRYN.jpg"

Comment: For clarity, your example does not have a `status` child so any query on `status` would return no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your snapshot, this should work

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('/tutor/' + userId).once('value').orderBy('approve_status')
  .equalTo('1').then((snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val().bio);
  // Data you want...
});
```

Try the firebase documentation to get more idea about queries [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data)

Comment: @BusyTech Hold up a sec. I don't think this is correct. There is no `status` node in the screenshot (just an oversight I am sure) but this answer is a query on the specific path `/tutor/userId` which will NOT query the entire `tutor` nodes for *all users* where status = 1. It would only run a query on that path `/tutor/-MBTJ...` which won't work.

Comment: @Jay `approve_status` is given, thanks for suggesting the edit

Comment: It's still not correct `.ref('/tutor/' + userId).` will not query the entire tutor node for ALL the nodes where approve_status = '1'. It will only query the /tutor/userId node which wasn't what the OP asked. But - it was accepted so maybe they figured it out anyway.