# Firebase and PHP - Select table by a field

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to select a firestore database table by the "client_name" field. But I can only select it by the "documentId" field. When I go to try errors appear, like:"Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function" are occurring.

To select the table by id use:

```
public function getServiceOrder(): array {
   
       return $this->firestore->collection(name: "service_orders")
        ->document(documentId: $_GET["id"])->snapshot()->data();
   
}
```

Currently, to try to select by name, I do this:

```
public function getServiceOrderName(): array {

        return $this->firestore->collection('material_detail'). where('name_client=') . $_GET["name"];
}
```

I already tried these ways (all inside the public function):

```
return $this->firestore->collection("os_detalhe_material")->document(documentId: "SELECT * FROM os_detalhe_material WHERE name_cliente= '" . $_GET['name'] . "'") -> snapshot()->data();
```

AND

```
$searchDetalhe = $db->getReference('os_detalhe_material/name_client/adrian')->getSnapshot()->getValue();
```

How do I select the table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a query in Firebase like SELECT \* FROM table WHERE status = '1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64993829/how-to-write-a-query-in-firebase-like-select-from-table-where-status-1)